# What is the meaning of "&" when dealing with condition formula with cell reference rather than fixed numbers

Tags: excel

I want to count the number that the value in a specified group is bigger than some value (which is in another cell).

For example:

```
     A     B     C
  -------------------
1 |  5  |  4  |  3  |
2 |  5  |  2  |  1  |
3 |  6  |  4  |  3  |
4 |  7  |  5  |  5  |
5 |  3  |  6  |  6  |
6 |  1  |  9  |  8  |
  -------------------
```

I want to count:

- in the range of `A2:A6`, how many is greater than `A1`;
- in the range of `B2:B6`, how many is greater than `B1`;
- in the range of `C2:C6`, how many is greater than `C1`;

I input the following formula (found it via Google):

`COUNTIF(A2:A6, ">"&A1)`

Actually I do not understand what is this `&` symbol for in EXCEL. Can anyone explain this?

Thanks,

Comment: What happens if you type `&` in a cell and highlight it and then press the magic key `F1` in Excel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`"&"` is the concatenation operator. It joins two strings together and returns a string.

**Edit**

I recommend searching help for the `CONCATENATE` and `COUNTIF` functions. The latter doesn't explicitly specify that argument 2 must evaluate to a `String` but it is implied in [COUNTIF function help](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34?NS=EXCEL&Version=16&SysLcid=1033&UiLcid=1033&AppVer=ZXL160&HelpId=xlmain11.chm60394&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US/%22COUNTIF%20function%22) under Common Problems.

The operators >; <; <>; must be embedded within double quotes `""` or the string evaluation will fail.  You can `CONCATENATE` strings using the shorthand `&` character.

If you want to count the number of 5s in a range, 5 doesn't have to be in double quotes -  `=COUNTIF(C1:C7,5)` but if you put an equal sign before 5, they must be in quotes `=COUNTIF(C1:C7,"=5")`

`COUNTIF(A2:A6, ">"&A1)` evaluates to `COUNTIF(A2:A6, ">5")` whereas `COUNTIF(A2:A6, >&A1)` and `COUNTIF(A2:A6, >5)` will both throw errors.

Comment: Mark is right but it might be easier to understand if you look at the basic countif criteria first and then show this solution as a way to compare to an existing cell.  i.e. `COUNTIF(A2:A6, ">1")` where the criteria is a string ">1".  To get a string and compare with a cell dynamically you have to concatenate. ">" & A1

Comment: @PortlandRunner, I agree.  I was in a hurry for a prior engagement.  I would've recommended searching help for CONCATENATE and COUNTIF.  The latter doesn't explicitly specify that argument 2 must evaluate to a String but it is implied. I would have added that operators     >; <; <>;     must be embedded within Quotation marks or the string evaluation will fail.  I should have shown that    COUNTIF(A2:A6, ">"&A1) evaluates to     COUNTIF(A2:A6, ">5")  whereas     COUNTIF(A2:A6, >&A1) and     COUNTIF(A2:A6, >5) will both throw errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the "**&**" symbol as and **AND** operator because it is the concatenation operator.

For your purpose you can just use the function **COUNTIFS** which is the same as **COUNTIF** but has many conditions to set.

Have a look [at this examples](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countifs-function-HA010047494.aspx) to understand how easily it works.